# When using the -p option in tar, is it required during creation, extraction, or both?

Tags: tar

---

When I use the -p option in tar (preserve permissions), do I need to use the
option during both the creation AND extraction of the archive, or just ONE of
them?

I'm unable to find a **definitive** answer to this question, and "man tar" doesn't
make it clear either.

So, I wonder if you could tell me please, which of the following needs the
"p":

```
$ tar cpf archive.tar source-files     # Create an archive.
$ tar xpf archive.tar                  # Extract the archive.
```

I'm interested to know if only one of the commands requires the "p", rather
than just use a blanket solution of using "p" in both.

Comment: The manpage makes it pretty clear that it's for extraction.

Answer (score 8):

`tar` stores the permissions by default when creating an archive, so `p` isn't necessary with `c`. It *is* necessary with `x`, unless you're running as `root`; otherwise the current umask is applied instead of the stored permissions. See the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Setting-Access-Permissions.html#SEC82):

> ```
> --preserve-permissions
> --same-permissions
> -p
> ```
>
> Set modes of extracted archive members to those recorded in the archive, instead of current umask settings. Use in conjunction with `--extract` (`--get`, `-x`).