# What are JDK default user and group?

Tags: rhel, users, group, jdk

I have a freshly installed jdk1.8.0_121 on my redhat machine. When I `ls -la` in the installation directory, following output is received,

```
total 178952
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root        root               87 Mar 23 16:00 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 19 root        root              256 Mar 23 18:19 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  8   10         143              255 Dec 12 19:50 jdk1.8.0_121
-rw-r--r--.  1 root        root        183246769 Dec 14 14:42 jdk-8u121-linux-x64.tar.gz
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root        root                6 Mar  9  2015 rh
```

My concern is with this line,

`drwxr-xr-x.  8   10         143              255 Dec 12 19:50 jdk1.8.0_121`

Are these user ("10", for which there is no corresponding user) and group ("143", for which there is no corresponding group) expected or have I missed something while installation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That just means that the tarball stores files with user id (UID) of 10 and group id (GID) of 143, and since you extracted it as root, [those identifiers were preserved](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/349182/86440). You haven’t missed anything, but you could `chown` the files to root:

```
chown -R root:root jdk1.8.0_121
```

This will avoid any surprises in future, should a user ever have id 10 on your system.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not have a user, in the same way python does not have a user. As it is something that you will be letting any user run, you may wish to locate it in /usr/local/jdk_version and symlink with /usr/local/jdk.

Tomcat, jenkins etc can reference this from their start up scripts.

As Stephen points out, you should chown this to prevent future user ID 8 from taking ownership.